# Copy AMI across multiple accounts and regions

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-ami

Currently the below Terraform code is reading the AMI from one AWS account and copying the AMI to another account, but we want the AMI to be copied to multiple regions within the account.

The AWS provider version = 4.51.0

```
data "aws_region" "current" {}

data "aws_ami" "eks_ami" {
  for_each = toset(data.aws_ami_ids.eks_ami_id.ids)
  filter {
    name   = "image-id"
    values = [each.key]
  }
  owners = [""]
}

data "aws_ami_ids" "eks_ami_id" {
  owners = ["12345"]

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["node-*"]
  }
}

data "aws_kms_key" "by_alias" {
  key_id = "alias/demokey"
}

module "kube_ami" {
  source = "./modules/ami/kube-ami"
  for_each          = toset(data.aws_ami_ids.eks_ami_id.ids)
  name              = data.aws_ami.eks_ami[each.key].name
  source_ami_id     = each.key
  source_ami_region = data.aws_region.current.name
  encrypted         = true
  kms_key_id        = data.aws_kms_key.by_alias.arn
}
```

```
resource "aws_ami_copy" "ami" {
  name              = var.name
  source_ami_id     = var.source_ami_id
  source_ami_region = var.source_ami_region
  encrypted         = var.encrypted
  kms_key_id        = var.kms_key_id
}
```

Comment: If this is a custom AMI then copying the AMI to multiple regions is easily handled with Packer.

Comment: Other than using packer which is a good choice, you can also try looping your `aws_ami_copy` resource. There's some good examples here https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/terraform-for-each-examples/ & with HashiCorp docs.

Comment: @MattSchuchard i am creating my ami using packer, using packer we are sharing the ami to multiple region but Tags are getting lost